# install odl-ovsdb-southbound-impl exception

Tags: openflow, opendaylight

In opendaylight carbon when installing 
 **feature:install odl-ovsdb-southbound-impl**

**I get the following exception**

```
Exception in thread "Thread-133" java.net.BindException: Address already in use   at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:128)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:554)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1258)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:502)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:487)
at io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler.bind(LoggingHandler.java:191)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:502)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:487)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:980)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:250)
at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:365)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:403)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:445)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**I also get it each time I start the ODL**

Comment: it looks like the problem is in port 6640, that I used in the command     sudo ovs-vsctl set-manager ptcp:6640     , I did not figure out why this is a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `java.net.BindException: Address already in use` means that something on the host you are running already holds one of the ports which OpenDaylight wants to open.  This could also happen if you start OpenDaylight twice.  Often the actual port is shown in this kind of error, and then you can use (on Linux) netstat to find what process is already on that port.  In this case for some reason its not showing which port; I don't know why.  So you could just do some trial and error and stop other things you are running one after the other one, and retry ODL, until you'll find what it is.

Comment: thank you for your response, I figured out the problem as I was trying to use the port 6640 will it is used. I was trying to set a connection to the ODL. I just used another port 6642, and it worked fine :)